# Adding images to UIScrollview with horizontal infinity style scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

So I'm doing my first UIScrollview by placing resized images into it, however when I get to the end of the first set of results and go to add the 2nd set etc., the view resets to the start. I'm not sure if it's adding the images, as the x value is being counted forward correctly, so the UIScrollview should be resizing, so I can only assume its just placing the next set of images on top of the old images.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
-(void)addScrollViewImages {
    // setup our UIScrollview
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    // hit our server for the data
    NSString *encodedKeywords =[self.keyword stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.results = [self fetchImageResults:encodedKeywords];

    // loop over some image results
    for (id image in self.results)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(self.x, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHight)];

        NSString *imageUrl = image[@"url"];
        NSData *image = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];

        // resize the image to the device
        [imageView setImage:[self imageScaleCropToSize:[UIImage imageWithData:image]]];

        [self.scrollView addSubview: imageView];
        self.x = (self.x + imageView.frame.size.width);

        // resize frame width
        if(self.x > self.view.frame.size.width) self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.x, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }
}
// This just gets the json data and processes it a little
-(NSArray*)fetchImageResults:(NSString*)keyword {
    //This should be fairly quick
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/api/v1/search?q=%@", keyword]];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:apiURL];
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    return result[@"results"];
}
// Scroll index management
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    float indexNum = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    if(floor(indexNum) == indexNum) {
        int num = (int)indexNum;

        NSLog(@"viewing %@",self.results[num]);

        // if we are at the end, load more
        if(num == (self.results.count-1) ) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self addScrollViewImages];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel the code is correct. Just try to resize frame width before adding ImageView to it i.e. move this code a bit up `if(self.x > self.view.frame.size.width) self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.x, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);`

Comment: I think you should very seriously consider using a `UITableView` for this. You could display each image in an individual `UITableViewCell` (possibly a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass of your own design). Why? Because UITableView is already designed to easily display infinite (or at least very large) lists of objects via its "reusable cell" feature. It will save you a ton of work. If you are not familiar with UITableView, check out Apple's documentation on this class (and its data source and delegate) for details. Pay particular attention to any method containing `reusable` in its name.

Comment: Shuffled it around, made no difference... As I noted below I started this project with UITableView, however scrolling horizontal became problematic with UITableView as its designed to scroll up/down, and everyone recommended that I use the UIScrollView.

Comment: Okay, I have another question: What exactly do you mean by "it resets to the beginning"? So you're able to successfully scroll through the carousel, and when it's time to load a new set, it loads the same set of images?

Comment: So my api only has 3 images to call from, so for now with testing I'm just stacking the same request over again. After the first time loading 3 images and I get to the end, it will load the next set of images. However, the scroll view jumps back to the start as if you just started the first round.

Comment: A third party for just what you are looking https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: I'm not sure if its just placing the next set on top of the old ones and thats way its resetting. However checking the global value of x, its recording correctly, and the scroll frame is resizing as it does it each time for each image in the turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

For starters I never initiated the results NSMutableArray at the start in viewDidLoad method

```
    self.results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Once I changed that, all I had to do was update my scroll method

```
// Scroll index management
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    float indexNum = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    float currentPosition = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x;

    if(floor(indexNum) == indexNum) {
        int num = (int)indexNum;
        // if we are at the end, load more
        if(num == ([self.results count]-1)) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self addScrollViewImages];
                [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currentPosition, 0.0)];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are killing yourself by not using a `UITableView`. Just make a `UITableView` with prototype `UITableViewCells`. Subclass a cell, `imageViewTableCell`, and make its only property a `UIImageView` that fills its size.

The rest is simply using the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

[Tutorial for setting up a tableview](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

Comment: That is where I started with this project, however scrolling horizontal became problematic with UITableView as its designed to scroll up/down, and everyone recommended that I use the UIScrollView.

Comment: Okay I apologize. I misunderstood your question.